# Cannot connect HTML file to CSS file which are both within the same folder

Tags: html, css

This is an image of my workspace
[image: VS CODE IMAGE HTML]

This is an image of my CSS workspace
[image: VS CODE IMAGE CSS]

VS Code links the styles.css in the href="styles.css" line in the link tag and that leads me perfectly to the styles.css file so I'm unsure why it is not linking. I have tried a lot of things from the internet and nothing has worked.

Comment: By "cannot connect", do you mean loading from a browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the answers that say to remove the trailing s are correct.
[Here's a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) to the MDN web docs on the  element. p.s., don't feel bad about this, it's just a simple mistake that anyone can make.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

it should be ->  link rel='stylesheet'

you have mistakenly added and extra "s" as "stylesheets"

Answer (score 2):

Change `stylesheets` into `stylesheet`  remove **s**

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css' type='text/css' media='all'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

change your file path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css">
```